# I am trying to provide a ranking based on a previous partition

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions, ranking

I am trying to change the ranking column where instead of ordering `by RMSE ASC` I want to `order by RMSESum ASC` (which was a previous `partition by`)….when I do this I get an error that **"ordered analytic functions cannot be nested"** any idea around this?

```
Select material, plant, fiscper, dmd_final_Fcst, sum_final_dmd_qty, 
row_number() Over (partition by material, plant order by **RMSE ASC**) as **Ranking**,
Sum(RMSE) over (partition by material, plant) as **RMSESum**,
Power(Fcst_er,2) As Sq_er,
dmd_final_fcst - sum_final_dmd_qty As Fcst_Er,
Sqrt(MSE) As RMSE,
Avg(Sq_er) as MSE 
from PRD_DWH_PURCHASING.HistoricalForecastVal
group by 1,2,3,4,5;
```

Comment: Your query has multiple errors -- even without that one.  You have lots of unaggregated columns in the `select`, for instance.

Comment: You got multiple rows per `material, plant` and `RMSESum` will be the same value for all of them, thus the ROW_NUMBER will be random. I doubt this is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the sub-query as follows:

```
SELECT T.*,
       row_number() Over (partition by material, plant order by RMSESum ASC) as Ranking
FROM
(Select material, plant, fiscper, dmd_final_Fcst, sum_final_dmd_qty,
       Sum(RMSE) over (partition by material, plant) as RMSESum,
       Power(Fcst_er,2) As Sq_er,
       dmd_final_fcst - sum_final_dmd_qty As Fcst_Er,
       Sqrt(MSE) As RMSE,
       Avg(Sq_er) as MSE
  from PRD_DWH_PURCHASING.HistoricalForecastVal
 group by 1,2,3,4,5) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
select * from (Select material, plant, fiscper, dmd_final_Fcst, sum_final_dmd_qty, 
row_number() Over (partition by material, plant order by RMSE ASC) as **Ranking**,
Sum(RMSE) over (partition by material, plant) as RMSESum,
Power(Fcst_er,2) As Sq_er,
dmd_final_fcst - sum_final_dmd_qty As Fcst_Er,
Sqrt(MSE) As RMSE,
Avg(Sq_er) as MSE 
from PRD_DWH_PURCHASING.HistoricalForecastVal)
order by RMSESum
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mix window functions and aggregation without using a subquery:

```
select material, plant, fiscper, dmd_final_Fcst, sum_final_dmd_qty, 
       row_number() Over (partition by material, plant order by Sqrt(MSE)) as Ranking
       sum(RMSE) over (partition by material, plant) as RMSESum,
       Power(Fcst_er, 2) As Sq_er,
       dmd_final_fcst - sum_final_dmd_qty As Fcst_Er,
       Sqrt(MSE) As RMSE,
       Avg(Sq_er) as MSE 
from PRD_DWH_PURCHASING.HistoricalForecastVal
group by 1,2,3,4,5;
```

But I still don't think this will work.  You have a bunch of unaggregated columns.  I am guessing you don't need the aggregation at all and really want:

```
select material, plant, fiscper, dmd_final_Fcst, sum_final_dmd_qty, 
       row_number() Over (partition by material, plant order by Sqrt(MSE)) as Ranking
       sum(RMSE) over (partition by material, plant) as RMSESum,
       Power(Fcst_er, 2) As Sq_er,
       dmd_final_fcst - sum_final_dmd_qty As Fcst_Er,
       Sqrt(MSE) As RMSE,
       Avg(Sq_er) over (partition by material, plant, fiscper, dmd_final_Fcst, sum_final_dmd_qty) as MSE 
from PRD_DWH_PURCHASING.HistoricalForecastVal;
```